# Typesetting UML class diagrams

Tags: diagrams

What's the best way to draw UML class diagrams in LaTeX?

Comment: Would you mind adding a little context, or a link to a description or (better still) a picture of the sort of thing that you'd like?  Someone may be able to help but not know what a UML diagram is.  Thanks!

Comment: UML stands for unified modelling language. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#Diagrams_overview

Answer (score 86, accepted):

- [MetaUML](https://github.com/ogheorghies/MetaUML) is a MetaPost library for typesetting UML diagrams with a human-friendly textual notation. Another useful package is emp. It allows to embed Metapost code and therefore MetaUML inside a LaTeX document
- [`pst-uml`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-uml) is a  PSTricks package providing support for drawing UML diagrams.
- [`uml`](http://ctan.org/pkg/uml) is another package using PSTricks implementing at least a subset
- [pgf/TikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) is so feature rich that it can be used for typesetting UML diagrams as well
- [`tikz-uml`](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ekielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en) is a UML-specialized TikZ package

Comment: My guess would be that this is the sort of algorithmic-drawing example where Metapost would be a natural choice, but that fits for GraphViz, too.

Comment: See Giel's answer for a pgl library.

Comment: +1 MetaUML looks really nice both the syntax and the output.

Comment: I highly recommend tikz-uml, very flexible, comprehensive and nice looking. Support the author, please. All other packages are very old (last, about 2006) and based on old packages,... pgf-Tikz is too generic.

Answer (score 18):

For UML class diagrams I'd recommend [`pgf-umlcd`](https://github.com/xuyuan/pgf-umlcd), for sequence diagrams [`pgf-umlsd`](https://github.com/xuyuan/pgf-umlsd) ([example by the author](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/pgf-umlsd/)). Both packages are based on the PGF package collection, which I find very easy to use for drawing vector graphics within TeX & LaTeX.

Comment: Your link is broken, there's some extra text at the end.

Comment: Try this link instead: http://www.loria.fr/~quinson/blog/2010/11/05/UML_class_diagrams_in_tikz/

Comment: Correct link is now: http://www.loria.fr/~quinson/blog/2010/1105/UML_class_diagrams_in_tikz/. TeXample using [pgf-umlsd](http://code.google.com/p/pgf-umlsd/): http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pgf-umlsd/

Answer (score 13):

A nice package I found a while ago is this: [TikZ-UML](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ekielbasi/tikzuml/).

It provides:

- Class diagrams.
- Use cases.
- State-transitions.
- Sequence diagrams.

It works pretty well, at least with the sequence diagrams I used.

Comment: The install section says "coming soon" for probably quite a while already. Don't be discouraged, the downloadable archive contains nice examples.

Answer (score 8):

(Lifted from Dima's answer to [my question on flowcharts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723/how-to-typeset-flowcharts-in-latex).) You can also use the Dot language and [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/). With [UMLGraph](http://www.umlgraph.org/) you can generate GraphViz specs, and use [dot2tex](http://www.fauskes.net/nb/introducing-dot2tex/) or Mark Aufflick's [graphviz.sty](http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2007/03/25/embedding-graphviz-in-latex-documents) to embed the graphs into LaTeX.

Comment: auto-upvote =)))))

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth, yet another option is [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/).

PlantUML takes pseudo-code-y plain-text class descriptors and generates UML diagrams (as PNG, SVG or EPS, possibly others).  It's a Java-based program that uses Graphviz on the back-end to determine layouts.

In addition to class/object diagrams, PlantUML can also generate other UML diagrams like sequence, activity, state, use case diagrams.

There's nothing particularly LaTeX-specific about it, and you'll probably need or want to store the class descriptors in an independent file but I've often used PlantUML (or for that matter, [ditaa](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/)) as part of a LaTeX publishing workflow.

Comment: i recommend the `eps` format to export, because its lossless and latex can use it natively

Answer (score 7):

While I guess there are nicer ways to do it, I recently came across [this example on texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/class-diagram/) on one way to produce UML diagrams with TikZ.

Comment: The nice thing about this is that it doesn't break TikZ relative positioning .. some of the other solutions appear to require manual positioning of all elements.

Comment: I had problems with \draw{myarrow} trying to replicate the example. I got the error _! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.230     \draw[myarrow]
                         (CoolingSystem.north) -- ++(0,0.8) -| (System.south);_

Comment: I fix it. http://algunostutoriales.blogspot.com/2014/03/arreglar-un-extrano-error-de-latex.html

Answer (score 4):

Tangentially related to [Willie's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/875/typsetting-uml-class-diagrams/884#884), if you think you might use [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to generate the diagrams, you might consider [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

This approach would be especially handy if you have more documentation than just the diagrams to create.  Doxygen is intended to document software projects. If you have a set of classes in C++ or java, then you can use doxygen to generate latex from the source code.  It can automatically generate several types of diagrams from the source, including UML class diagrams all hyperlinked and integrated with the rest of the documentation and its source code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a native LaTeX solution but [PlantText](https://www.planttext.com/) is also a good online editor for creating a lot of different diagramms that can be saved as `SVG`.