# Is there any package to model use diagrams of UML?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typsetting UML class diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/875/typsetting-uml-class-diagrams)

I need to model some diagrams UML, specially use cases, but I didn't find a good package to do this, I found **[UML for LaTeX/MetaPost](http://metauml.sourceforge.net/old/index.html)** however it doesn't have good results as I wanted. Do you have a package or template for this goal?

Comment: Please have a look at [Typsetting UML class diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/875/typsetting-uml-class-diagrams). We would close this question as a duplicate, as it's already been dealt with. Feel free to contribute to the other question and its answers.

Comment: There's also TikZ: [“Adventure UML” in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5328/adventure-uml-in-tex).

Comment: But there isn't package for Use Cases.

Comment: It is: [use case diagram with MetaUML](http://metauml.sourceforge.net/old/usecase-diagram.html).

Comment: I recommend you the package [TikZ-UML](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en). I put my answer in the question cited by @Stefan: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/875/typsetting-uml-class-diagrams/34519#34519

Comment: That's such I need