# Generate Entity-Relationship Diagram then generate SQL from that

Tags: diagrams, metauml

Using a LaTeX or similar text-macro tool/library, how can I generate an Entity-Relationship Diagram then generate SQL from it?

Comment: Can you post a bit more detail as to exactly what you want. Perhaps a diagram and some code of what you have attempted.

Comment: IMHO, TikZ is the way to go for diagrams: See [typesetting uml class diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/875/typsetting-uml-class-diagrams) for more options.

Comment: I've decided to write the SQL by hand, and generate a diagram from that using SchemaSpy. Using Doc2TeX I can then embed it neatly into my TeX report.

Comment: But I want people to mark it down if they think it's a bad idea, or mark it up if they think it's a good one

Comment: This seems like the wrong way round. Wouldn't it be easier to write the SQL and then read that to create the diagram? Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: See my previous answer. I don't think it's a wrong method though, a lot of what we write is very repetitive, models which generate SQL are much more useful at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Run `texdoc pst-dbicons` then you'll get the documentation of `pst-dbicons`. But there is no package which can generate the corresponding sql code.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-er2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[entity/.style={draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick, rectangle, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=7mm}, attribute/.style={draw=black, fill=white, thick, ellipse, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=7mm}, relationship/.style={draw=red!50, fill=red!20, thick, diamond, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=7mm, aspect=2}]

\node[entity] (user) {User};
\node[attribute] (userid) [above left of=user] {\key{user\_id}} edge (user);
\node[attribute] (name) [above of=user] {name} edge (user);
\node[attribute] (email) [above right of=user] {email} edge (user);
\node[attribute] (password) [right of=user] {password} edge (user);

\node[entity] (product) [below of=user] {Product};
\node[attribute] (productid) [above left of=product] {\key{product\_id}} edge (product);
\node[attribute] (pname) [above of=product] {name} edge (product);
\node[attribute] (price) [above right of=product] {price} edge (product);
\node[attribute] (description) [right of=product] {description} edge (product);
\node[attribute] (categoryid) [below right of=product] {category\_id} edge (product);

\node[entity] (category) [below of=product] {Category};
\node[attribute] (categoryid2) [above left of=category] {\key{category\_id}} edge (category);
\node[attribute] (cname) [above of=category] {name} edge (category);
\node[attribute] (description2) [above right of=category] {description} edge (category);
\node[attribute] (parentid) [below left of=category] {parent\_id} edge (category);

\node[entity] (order) [right of=product, xshift=5cm] {Order};
\node[attribute] (orderid) [above left of=order] {\key{order\_id}} edge (order);
\node[attribute] (userid2) [above right of=order] {user\_id} edge (order);
\node[attribute] (productid2) [below left of=order] {product\_id} edge (order);
\node[attribute] (quantity) [below of=order] {quantity} edge (order);
\node[attribute] (date) [below right of=order] {date} edge (order);

\node[entity] (payment) [below of=order] {Payment};
\node[attribute] (paymentid) [above of=payment] {\key{payment\_id}} edge (payment);
\node[attribute] (amount) [left of=payment] {amount} edge (payment);
\node[attribute] (paymentmethod) [right of=payment] {payment\_method} edge (payment);
\node[attribute] (orderid2) [below left of=payment] {order\_
```