# Package for UML component diagrams?

Tags: packages, diagrams

Do you know any package to model **component diagrams** of UML?

There are some packages like [`tikz-uml`](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php) that support class diagrams or sequence diagrams, but I haven't found any for component diagrams.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/875/typsetting-uml-class-diagrams

Comment: Neither pst-uml, nor uml packages have component diagrams. MetaUML, yes, it has component diagrams, but I want something that wouldn't need invocation of any external programs (mpost in case of MetaUML).

Comment: Why was this closed? This asks specifically about "component diagrams" - which are not covered by any of the other packages in the other answer.