# How to create an instance in pgf-umlsd?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using Modelio but I want to do everything on my paper with LaTeX, so I chose pgf-umlsd to do my sequence diagram. The trouble I have is that I don't know how to create an message to create a instance with this library, can you help me? Check the image below where you can see what I'm talking about.

[image: this image]

My first code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newinst{act}{Actor}
    \newthread{nr}{NetRoute}
    \newthread{nr}{NetScan}
    \begin{call}{act}{ Buscar una red}{nr}{ redes }
        %\begin{call}{act}{ Buscar una red}{nr}{ redes }
    \end{call}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

Comment: Added, but I don't know how it can help. Thank you for your reply ;)

Comment: The full code was on WriteLatex, but changed it!

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what do you want. Could explain it better? Even hand drawing it over your result could help.

Comment: @Ignasi, You can see it on my picture using modelio. As you can see there, a lifetime create a instance of a class sending the message "create".

Comment: @Ignasi What I wanted to say is to have a "create" message command which creates a new instance but places the box at the message arrow's vertical position instead of at the very top of the diagram.

Comment: Does not seem like this is a feature of `pfg-umlsd` http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpgf-umlsd.googlecode.com%2Fgit-history%2Fbc853ab627d49800cd4d0346acba2740195846a3%2Ftags%2Fpgf-umlsd-0.6%2Fpgf-umlsd-manual.pdf&ei=LhSjU-vMCemp7Aa8_oDwBQ&usg=AFQjCNG8G-0L8GKOuleUjTLyi11TaLfGTg&sig2=NyOna1KgKZu6ivkvXhrWaw&bvm=bv.69411363,d.ZGU&cad=rja. But are you sure that this is the right way to do in a sequence diagram. Normally all the instances stay at the top.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi uff, do you know another packet which let me to do this? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to take a look on [TikZ-uml](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=doc#t-4) which defines such a macro (`\umlcreatecall{}{}`) for you. Just download the `tikz-uml.sty` into your main folder and compile the following:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlactor[class=A, fill=blue!20]{Actor}
\umlobject[class=B]{NetRoute}
\umlobject[class=C]{NetScan}
\umlcreatecall[class=D]{NetScan}{NetModel}
\begin{umlcall}[op={buscar una red}, return=redes]{NetScan}{NetModel}
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Which yields:

[image]

You should be able to adapt this to your needs. If not, it should still be possible t draw everything in TikZ or you have a look on [other possible solutions for drawing UML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/875).

Answer (score 1):

If I well understood, you want something like `\mess` but with a boxed label above and a line joining label and mid point.

You can do something similar *customizing* `\mess`. I've copied `\mess` definition from `pgf-umlsd.sty` to the preamble and changed a litle bit. The result is `\create{origin}{label}{destination}` command with similar syntax.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\newcommand{\create}[4][0]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess from) {};
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{#1}
  \path
  (#4)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (mess to) {};
  \draw[->,>=angle 60] (mess from) -- (mess to) node[midway, above=1mm, draw, inner sep=1pt] (create_aux_node)
  {#3} coordinate[midway] (create_aux);
   \draw (create_aux) -- (create_aux_node); 
  \node (#3 from) at (mess from) {};
  \node (#3 to) at (mess to) {};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \newinst{act}{Actor}
    \newthread{nr}{NetRoute}
    \newthread{ns}{NetScan}
    \begin{call}{act}{ Buscar una red}{ns}{ redes }
    \end{call}
    \create{act}{create}{nr}
\end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

[image]