# I have 9 class and I wanted to make a UML diagram of these in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have 9 class and I wanted to make a UML diagram of these in latex

[image]

Comment: What did you do so far, where do you have problems? Did you search this site for UML and found e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/875/typesetting-uml-class-diagrams or any of the other nearly 400 hits?

Comment: I need the code source to draw this uml diagram in latex

Comment: "I need the code source to draw this uml diagram in latex" what do you mean with this, the source code from which the original UML diagram was drawn (check with the author of the original diagram) or the LaTeX source code for the diagram. In the later case follow the suggestions I made in my initial comment and there are most likely some good starting points there. Note this is not a site to write your code but just to help with the problems you encounter in your, LaTeX, code.