# Text in framed boxes with arrows

Tags: positioning, arrows, framed

A question similar to [How can I construct a page layout with framed boxes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108374/how-can-i-construct-a-page-layout-with-framed-boxes)

I need to construct a very simple flow chart with a few vertically and horizontally aligned boxes with arrows betweem them.

As I'm not very experienced with LaTeX assistance I'd love some help!

What I'm after is something like this:

```
      +-----------------------------------------+
      | A few lines of text in a block,         |
      | centered would be nice but not required |
      +-----------------------------------------+
                         |
                         v
           o---------------------------o
           | A double box here perhaps?|
           o---------------------------o
                         |
            +------------+-------------+
            |                          |
            v                          v
   +------------------+   +--------------------------+
   |More words here   |   |     More words here      |
   +------------------+   +--------------------------+
```

Comment: Could you please post a picture of what exactly you'd like? (even something hand drawn would suffice) See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723/how-to-typeset-flowcharts-in-latex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Could you please also look at pp.210-212 of the pgf manual. I will adapt that for this and post an answer. Please also clarify what a double box is? Its frame is doubled?

Comment: Link to Manual: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: @Kan Thank you for the suggestion.  The picture on page 211 is a complex version of what I'm trying to do.  By 'double box' I did mean a box with a double frame to differentiate it from the other boxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my first attempt, there are several places to polish and I'd do them as I figure out how to do:-)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes}
\newlength{\mytw}
\settowidth{\mytw}{A few lines of text in a block}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[> = latex', auto,
block/.style ={rectangle,draw=black, thick,
align=flush center, rounded corners,
minimum height=4em},
]
\matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=7mm]
{
% row 1
&
\node [block, text width=\mytw] (firstbox) {A few lines of text in a block, centered would be nice but not required}; &
 \\
% row 2
& \node [block, double, double distance=1pt] (dbox) {A double box here perhaps?!}; & \\
% row 3
 & \node[inner sep = 0pt] (dummy) {}; & \\
%row 4
\node [block] (b1) {More text goes here};&
&\node [block] (b2) {more text goes here};\\
};

 \draw[->] (firstbox) -- (dbox);
 \draw[-] (dbox) -- (dummy); 
 \draw[->]    (dummy) -| (b1); 
 \draw[->]    (dummy) -| (b2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image: flow2e.png]

Comment: @erik Thank you very much.  Unfortunately my installation doesn't have the flowchart package and I'm not permitted to install it.

Comment: I'll take the code provided by @kan and play with it.  Thanks heaps for the assistance.

Comment: I was absolutely unable to make this one compile, kept getting `missing } inserted` and `missing \cr inserted` errors. I used the solution from below, but if anyone could shed light on this, then it might help future help-seekers.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using the [`flowchart` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowchart) (which is based on TikZ). See package documentation for details.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{flowchart}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, thick]

\node (A) at (0,0) [draw, process, text width=5cm, minimum height=0.5cm, align=flush center] 
{A few lines of text in a block, centered would be nice but not required};

\node (B) at (0,-2) [draw, double, double distance=1pt, process, minimum height=0.5cm, align=flush center] 
{A double box here perhaps?};

\node (C) at (-3,-4) [draw, process, minimum height=0.5cm, align=flush center] 
{Some words here};

\node (D) at (3,-4) [draw, process, minimum height=0.5cm, align=flush center] 
{More words here};

\coordinate (z) at (0,-3);

\draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\draw[->] (B) -- (z) -| node[above] {NO} (C);
\draw[->] (B) -- (z) -| node[above] {YES} (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]