# Drawing Flow Chart with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-styles, trees, technical-drawing

TikZ can draw flow chart but I want some sort of a graphical tool where I can create flowchart in an interactive way and then somehow export to LaTeX. Any advice? I am not a geek and the interface should not be too intimidating. An on-line tool or an off-line package will be fine, but it should run on Linux.

Comment: MAybe you find some inspiration in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723/how-to-typeset-flowcharts-in-latex

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dia is an open source program for drawing vector graphics. I find it quite handy for drawing diagrams and schematic drawings. [Dia Examples](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/Examples)

Dia exports graphics into vector and pixel formats as well as TikZ/PGF macros.

Comment: Thanks. The native format is .dia, right? What's the best way to export a flowchart to LaTex, particularly as TikZ? Can I get direct codes, like latexdraw?

Comment: Wes, the native format is *.dia. Sometimes, I export a graphics to TikZ and edit the TikZ file directly (by default dia writes the TikZ code in a *.tex file).

Comment: Thanks, I found the option. But I have latex commands inside the node texts which must be processed by tex. When I put the latex commands, dia escapes them characters to produce them verbatim. I can put the desired texts in the tex macro itself, but that completely messes up with the box sizes. Any way out?

Comment: In this case I edit the exported file with a text-editor directly. This is just a work-around, but unfortunately, I can't think of a more beautiful solution.

Answer (score 2):

you could use svg, open it in inkscape and use the workflow as in the accepted answer from [Exporting from Inkscape to LaTeX - via TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz)

Inkscape also offers the possibility to use connectors, but in my view dia ist the best tool to start, then maybe use inkscape to give it the final touch.

Answer (score 1):

Since some time has passed since the last answers, here is the browser-based tool that I find very helpful nowadays:

[mathcha.io](https://www.mathcha.io)

It has flow chart and math support and exports to TikZ nicely!