# Is there a (tikz) package that supports flowcharts according to ISO 5807?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, charts, iso

I wonder if there is a package that fully supports the flowchart symbols defined in ISO 5807:1985 (or at least a hugh amount of them)? I just found the `tikz` [flowchart package](http://tug.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/flowchart/flowchart.pdf) from Adrian P. Robson. But this only contains five symbols.

So does anybody know a package which provides a larger range of symbols?

Comment: As this is a quite expensive standard, you should add some picture of what you want to have. I guess you will be most lucky with TikZ as most people are using this for flow charts nowadays. You can have a look on the related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/723 However: just have a look on the TikZ library `shapes` and define all the shapes you need by your own. We will help you, if you encounter any problems.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Yes i know that, but nevertheless i wanted to know, if someone provided a bigger package. I used the package I mentioned in my post, because it matched my purpose in this particular case. I just asked for the future, if there is something more powerfull :)

Comment: You can find some additional shapes for flowcharts in [Claudio's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87956/1952)