# Help with a diagram in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How can I draw this in LaTeX without colour (only black and white)?

[image]

I managed to get my code  to represent every part but I need the arrow in the middle

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[sharp corners=2pt,inner sep=7pt,node distance=.8cm,every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=orange!30, 
    text width=10em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]

% Draw rectangular nodes (switch sharp to smooth for different corners)
\node[draw, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 1cm] (state0){Lecture hall A };
\node[draw,below=1cm of state0, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 1cm](state2){ Female students };
\node[draw,right=1cm of state0, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 1cm](state1){Lecture hall A };
\node[draw,below=1cm of state1, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 1cm](state3){Male students};
width = 1cm](state2){ Female students };
\node[draw,right=2cm of state3, minimum height = 1cm, minimum
width = 1cm](state4){ Female students };
\node[draw,right=1cm of state4, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 1cm](state5){Male students};
\node [block, right=3cm of state1] (state6) {Lecture hall A};
%Draw arrows
\draw[-triangle 60] (state0) -- (state2) node [midway, above, left = 0.1cm]{};

\draw[-triangle 60] (state1) -- (state3) node [midway, above, right = 0.1cm]{};

\draw[-triangle 60] (state6) -- (state4) node [midway, above, right = 0.1cm]{};
\draw[-triangle 60] (state6) -- (state5) node [midway, above, right = 0.1cm]{};
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: my trying this code represent the left part only

Comment: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close. Don't forget, it's a new user!

Comment: Review this postinghttp://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723/how-to-typeset-flowcharts-in-latex/99280#99280  for some ideas as you build your MWE showing what you can do and specifically how we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[sharp corners=2pt,inner sep=7pt,node distance=.8cm,every text node part/.style={align=center}]

% Draw rectangular nodes (switch sharp to smooth for different corners)
\node[draw] (state0){Lecture hall A };
\node[draw,below=2.5em of state0](state2){ Female students };
\node[draw,right=2em of state0](state1){Lecture hall A };
\node[draw,below=2.5em of state1](state3){Male students};
%Blank node for positioning
\node[right=2em of state1](blank){};
%Arrow
\node[single arrow, draw=black, fill=black!25, minimum height=4em, below=0.9em of blank](arrow){};
\node[draw, right=7em of state1, minimum height = 5em, minimum width =9em](state4){Lecture hall A};
%Blank node for positioning
\node[below=4em of state4](invis){};
\node[draw, below left=1em of invis](state5){Female students};
\node[draw, below right=1em of invis](state6){Male students};

%Draw arrows
\draw[-triangle 60] (state0) -- (state2) node [midway, above, left = 0.1cm] {};
\draw[-triangle 60] (state1) -- (state3) node [midway, above, right = 0.1cm] {};
\draw[-triangle 60] (state4.south) -- (state5);
\draw[-triangle 60] (state4.south) -- (state6);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]