# How to make the flow chart in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams, charts, workflow

How to make the flow chart in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Please refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723/how-to-typeset-flowcharts-in-latex

Answer (score 1):

There is a flow chart package which you can use. The documentation is given here, please check:

```
http://ctan.imsc.res.in/graphics/pgf/contrib/flowchart/flowchart.pdf
```