# how to draw a flow chart In latex with a figure

Tags: flow-charts

I need some suggestions for drawing flowchart for my process. The whole process is divided into three modules

1. Module 1 Random: The inputs to this module are two scalars $m$ and $n$. It outputs to matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.
2. Module 2 Deterministic: The input here is a range of angle $\theta$. It outputs two vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ computed from a fixed relationship involving $\theta$
3. Module 3: It combines $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B},\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ according to a known relationship.

My question is

1. I want have three separate boxes for these the modules. Module 1 and 2 are drawn in parallel in top half of chart. Module 3 that goes in bottom half extends from southwest corner to module 1 to southeast corner of module 2.
2. Since within each module module I need to show its internal process, I want to have a flexible code so that change in one does not effect other blocks.
3. In Module 2, I want to draw a circle showing $\theta$ (like below)

[image]

Which tool should I be using to draw this flowchart?

Comment: This isn't your first question about drawing diagrams. You must, by now, know the tools available. Or, if you don't, we obviously aren't being much help. This is just a do-it-for-me as far as I can tell, and not an especially intelligible one at that.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723/how-to-typeset-flowcharts-in-latex tells you the tools available. Although the question asks for a simpler case, the answer lists tools suitable for more complicated charts, too. Since you already use Ti*k*Z and it will be easy to draw the circle etc. with that approach, that's the most obvious strategy. Obviously, you might have unspecified desiderata which indicate one of the other options, however.

Comment: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/flowcharts/